# Is there a way to represent the image obtained by ImageDifference between 0 and 1?

Tags: image-processing

I would like to use ImageDifference to express the change in motion between 0 and 1.

```
Dynamic[{data = CurrentImage[2], smart = ImageDifference[data[[1]], data[[2]]]}]
```

If there is no change, 0,
Depending on the degree of change, I want to represent between 0 and 1.

Is there a way to represent the image obtained by ImageDifference between 0 and 1?

Comment: Probably many ways e.g. you can sum up grayscaled image and normalize with respect to pixel count. But this question is not about Mathematica.

Comment: Good idea thank you. I wanted to know if there was a Mathematica function that would solve this problem easily. And I found a function called ImageMeasurements.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ImageAdjust`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAdjust.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add up the all the pixel values and then divide by the total number of pixels in the image.

```
Dynamic[data = CurrentImage[2]; 
   {smart = ImageDifference[data[[1]], data[[2]]], 
   {n, m} = ImageDimensions[smart]; 
   Total[Flatten@ImageData[smart]]/(n m)}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers. 
I used to find a function called ImageMeasurements, and I got results similar to your answer.

value = Dynamic@ImageMeasurements[smart, "MeanIntensity"];

Comment: @user21427 You should post your solution as self-answer and accept it in order to take this question off the list of unanswered questions.